# Spring Data ArangoDB : Save parent and child together

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, parent-child, arangodb

I am trying to build my Java Spring Boot interpretation of saving ArangoDB nodes. My code looks like below
Asset.java

```
@Data
@Document("assets")
public class Asset {

    @Id
    String key;
    String name;
    String description;
    String path;
    LocalDateTime imported_at;
}
```

and AssetContent.java as

```
@Data
@Document("asset_contents")
public class AssetContent {

    @Id
    String key;
    String name;
    String extension;
    String content;
}
```

ChildOf.java to give a relation between Asset and AssetContent

```
@Data
@Edge("edges")
public class ChildOf<T1, T2> {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @From
    private T1 child;

    @To
    private T2 parent;

    public ChildOf(final T1 child, final T2 parent) {
        super();
        this.child = child;
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

where One Asset has multiple AssetContents. Now I want to achieve 3 things

1. Save an Asset and list of Asset Contents together.
2. Get the asset using the AssetContent repository.
3. Get the list of asset contents using the AssetRepository.

Since I am new to ArangoDB and also because of the limited documentation. Could someone help me with the changes I have to make in the code?

Answer (score 1):

1. Spring Data ArangoDB doesn't handle cascading operations. So if you save a parent, the child is not saved automatically. You can implement such functionality by yourself performing the 2 operations in sequence, but note that in this case there is no transactions support (https://github.com/arangodb/spring-data/issues/80).
2. In order to follow the edge from child to parent you can use the `@Relations` annotation (https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/drivers/spring-data-reference-mapping-relations.html). You can anyways return `Asset` from `AssetContentRepository`, eg.:

```java
public interface AssetContentRepository extends ArangoRepository<AssetContent, String> {

    @Query("<your AQL query returning Asset>")
    Asset findAsset(AssetContent assetContent);

}
```